# How do I dynamically sum input values inside a repeatable fields container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup in HTML:

```
<div class="rf-row count-container">
    <input class="sum-monthly">
        <div class="sub-rf-row">
            <input class="add-monthly">
        </div>
       <div class="sub-rf-row">
            <input class="add-monthly">
       </div>
       <div class="sub-rf-row template">
            <input class="add-monthly">
       </div>
</div>
```

And I want to add all inputs with class 'add-monthly' inside each sub-rf-row (excluding template sub-rf-rows) to the 'sum-monthly' inside rf-row (it's parent).

I want to calculate the sum values before user input (on document.ready). As well as dynamically update it on a 'keyup' event on one of the add-monthly inputs.

How can I best do this in jQuery?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
 $(document).ready(function()
 {

   updateValues()
   $('.sub-rf-row').keyup(updateValues); 

  });


function updateValues()
{
   var sum=0;
   $('.sub-rf-row:not(.template) input').each(function(){

     sum+=parseInt($(this).val()=='' ? 0 : $(this).val());
   });


    $('.sum-monthly').val(sum);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rt42fz9q/13/

Comment: I've added some labels to make it more clear: https://jsfiddle.net/jeuxt0gr/1/

How do I make this fiddle dynamic with keyup?

Comment: Okay I've almost got it working except for one thing: When I remove a row I want the sum-monthly to reflect this. However the value inside the removed row isn't subtracted from sum-monthly. Below is my current fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/rkfyx12o/

Comment: @RobertStrong what event you use to remove row ?

Comment: DOMNodeRemoved.

Comment: @RobertStrong just put  updateValues() at the end of the node removing logic and could you post node removing logic in fiddle link.

Answer (score 0):

In order to acheive your goal, you need to reference the desired `input` fields, iterate through them and calculate their sum, finally place that sum in the `.add-monthly` field. But you nedd to watch out for the non-numeric values that may be present in some fields, so, in the `sumUpdate` function below I only add the `input` field's value to the sum only if that value is a valid number, also decimal numbers are allowed.

Here's a snippet to illustrate all what being said:

```js
$(function(){
  var sumInput = $('.rf-row input.sum-monthly'), 
      /* the 'sumInput' variable is the input field that will display the sum of the other inputs */
      inputs = $('.sub-rf-row:not(.template) input.add-monthly'); 
  /* the 'inputs' variable is an array containing the input fields with the class '.add-monthly' that are under '.sub-rf-row' element which doesn't have  a '.template' class */
  
  // Call the updateSum function to calculate the sum directly after the document has loaded.
  updateSum();
  
  // Adding KeyUp event listener to the inputs
  inputs.on('keyup', updateSum);
  
  // Implementation of the updateSum function that will calcule the sum of the input fields.
function updateSum() {
    sum = 0;
    inputs.each(function() {
      var val = +$(this).val(); // Notice the plus sign in front of $(this).val() with we cast the input value to an integer, the val  variable could contain of value of NaN if the input value can't be casted to an input(in other words if the input value contains non-numeric characters). With that we also allow decimal numbers.
      sum += (val.toString() != 'NaN') ? val:0; // We only add valid numbers, otherwise we add 0 to the sum variable.
    });
    sumInput.val(sum.toFixed(2).replace('.00', '')); // Assign the sum variable's value to the sumInput, allowing precision to only 2 decimal digits, and also stripping '.00' from the sum variable if it contains a natural number(like 2.00 => 2, 10.00 => 10, but any decimal number will remain the same: 2.8 => 2.80, 12.97 => 12.97).
  }
});
```

```html
<!-- I added some values for the input fields with '.add-monthly' class just to show that the 'updateSum' function executes when the document is loaded -->
<div class="rf-row count-container">
    <input class="sum-monthly">
        <div class="sub-rf-row">
            <input class="add-monthly" value="2.4">
        </div>
       <div class="sub-rf-row">
            <input class="add-monthly" value="8.2">
       </div>
       <div class="sub-rf-row template">
            <input class="add-monthly">
       </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

*Ps: I added some helpful comments to the code above, try to read them as they may help you.*

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score -1):

This may help yours

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      Demo
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="rf-row count-container">
       <input class="sum-monthly">
            <div class="sub-rf-row">
                <input class="add-monthly" value="5">
            </div>
           <div class="sub-rf-row">
                <input class="add-monthly" value="5">
           </div>
           <div class="sub-rf-row template">
                <input class="add-monthly" value="5">
           </div>
    </div>

    <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
  var value = 0;
    $('.count-container .sub-rf-row').each(function(){
      value += parseInt($(this).find('.add-monthly').val()) ? parseInt($(this).find('.add-monthly').val()) : 0
    })
   $('.sum-monthly').val(value);
});

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdpZpR?editors=1010

Comment: this will include inputs with template class.